# Find all unique combinations of simple paths

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

Considering the following network example:

```
gg = nx.complete_graph(6)
paths = nx.all_simple_paths(gg, source=0, target=3, cutoff=5)
print(list(paths))

nx.draw(gg, with_labels = True)
```

The all_simple_paths() give back all possible paths between node (0, 3).
I need an alternative function that avoid to calculate a path if a node was previously used.

Comment: Paths of a specific length? If not, what if all nodes are used in the first path, is that a valid result?

Comment: I want all the paths and any length. The problem in a complete graph is that for example I have [0, 1, 2, 4, 3] but also [0, 1, 4, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4, 1, 3], [0, 4, 1, 2, 3] and I want to exclude this non-sense redundancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep the unique *combinations*  of paths, i.e. unique sets of nodes to reach to a target, you could build a `set` of `frozensets` from your paths, and back to a list.

Using a `frozenset` here, enables you to remove duplicates by building a `set` from the resulting iterable. Howerver, we'll have to rearange the resulting paths, since sets have no order. For that we can use a list comprehension, to build lists from those `frozensets` and enforce that the `source` and `target` nodes are at the beginning and end respectively:
So for the shared example:

```
gg = nx.complete_graph(6)

source = 0
target = 3
paths = nx.all_simple_paths(gg, source=source, target=target, cutoff=5)

s = set(map(frozenset, paths))
# {frozenset({0, 3, 4}), frozenset({0, 2, 3})...
non_redundant_paths = [[source, *[*p-{source,target}],target] for p in s]
```

Another way, possibly preferable since you only have to iterate once, is to iterate over the generator of paths, and keep track of the seen ones using a `set`:

```
non_redundant_paths = []
seen = []
for p in paths:
    if set(p) not in seen:
        non_redundant_paths.append(p)
        seen.append({*p})
```

---

```
print(non_redundant_paths)
[[0, 4, 3], [0, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 4, 3], [0, 1, 5, 3], [0, 2, 4, 3], 
 [0, 3], [0, 1, 4, 3], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3], [0, 2, 4, 5, 3], [0, 2, 5, 3], 
 [0, 4, 5, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 4, 5, 3], [0, 5, 3], [0, 1, 2, 5, 3], [0, 1, 3]]
```

Comment: Both great solutions. Thank you!

Comment: The only problem that I have now is that for large networks it takes a long time to run. I open a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63952593/unique-combinations-of-simple-paths-fro-all-graph?noredirect=1#comment113088776_63952593