# Unique combinations of simple paths fro all graph

Tags: python, networkx

Considering a very large network I need to calculate for all the pair edges all the simple paths.
If the network is large, it's hard to compute. So, I want all unique simple paths to speed up the process. Here an example:

```
gg = nx.complete_graph(1000) 

edgelist = nx.to_edgelist(gg)
sources = [s for s, t, d in edgelist]
targets = [t for s, t, d in edgelist]
weights = [d for s, t, d in edgelist]

for source in sources:
    for target in targets:
        paths = nx.all_simple_paths(gg, source, target)
        s = set(map(frozenset, paths))
        nx.set_edge_attributes(gg, 'unique_paths', s)
```

The code above gives back all simple path, and frozenset removes duplicates paths.
I need to check if the path was already used before calculating all simple paths

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Sure, consider to have this network: gg = nx.complete_graph(6). Running the code above and checking the result with: gg.edges(data=True) I have two main problems. First it gives back same set of paths for all pair of edges and it take long time to run if graph is complex. With complex I mean gg = nx.complete_graph(1000) for example.

Comment: To be more precise, for each pair of nodes in the network gg I need all the "unique simple paths" and add it with nx.set_edge_attribute().

Comment: @claudia may I ask what you mean by a unique path because `nx.all_simple_paths` shouldn't return any duplicate path as far as I know. And in your code you are mapping `frozenset` function to each path before removing the possible duplicates by putting them in a `set`, what is the purpose of `frozenset`?

Comment: @AzimMazinani considering for example this code: 
gg = nx.complete_graph(6)
paths = nx.all_simple_paths(gg, source=0, target=3, cutoff=5) 
in the results we have for example:
[0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 4, 2, 1, 5, 3]  

The "frozenset" avoid these sort of repetitions.
The problem is that "all_simple_paths" takes a ling time to run.
I need to find a way to find a way to exclude the repetions above, before calculating "all_simple_paths".